# How do I create ruled lines in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

My aim is to set up Word to use the 'Cornell Notetaking method', and I would like to be able to have 'ruled lines' as part of my page in word.

Currently, I have a split textbox, however obviously this does not allow the text to flow between lines. The underlining method does not work well enough, and I had read something about a college ruled template, however I was not able to find that.

So is there any solution at all - by **either creating lines in the textbox, or making the text flow between textbox rows?**

Comment: Are you saying you want a page covered in ruled lines, which remain under the text you typed, and in the blank spaces not yet filled in?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want the text to be able to flow through the page and to not have to manually start a new line when I reach the far side of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using tables.

Create tables and then using table properties set the border to only cell bottom.  You can play with the row height property until you find the size you are looking for.

You can also use [this template from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/lined-paper-TC030005376.aspx).

Comment: Cheers for that, however I am not sure what you mean with the table suggestion - I am after something that creates lines for every line on the page.
Sadly, the template suffers from the same problem as my table, where the text just wraps around into the table box.

Comment: Try playing with the margins/line height to get it to line up with the template.  I think the template is a better suggestion than the table anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The template just uses a table anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I created a solution when I needed a ruled medical progress note. The document I needed required some users to type into the form with the text staying within the ruled lines, AND the ability to hand write text on a blank printed form.  The typed text had to wrap to the next line and stay within the ruled lines.

I have been working on this for some time. I finally created this form by doing the following:

Open word and create a multi-lined table (about 30 rows with a .3" row height). The page has 1" borders and 1/2" headers, footers.

Next, I took a screen shot of the page using full screen and a handy program called Full Shot, a screen capture utility, and saved the image as a GIF file.

Next, I created a new Word document with 0" borders and 0" headers and footers. From the View menu, select Headers and Footers. Select Insert >  Image > From File and insert the image into the header. The full page image appears in the background, thus achieving the requirement for ruled lines. Next, right click the image, select Format Image, and select Layout > Behind Text. This causes additional insertions in the next steps to appear above the image.

Once you have the basic page, you must close and save the document and reopen it so you can get into the main document. Next, access the Forms toolbar and add a Form Frame around the area you wish to type into. This will cause a floating frame to appear over the ruled lines. Then add a text field inside the Form Frame.

Finally, choose Tools > Protect Document and allow filling in forms.

I would appreciate any feedback so that maybe we can perfect this method.

Comment: Wow, that's really clever. Far too complex for what I'm working on, but still, thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found that worked for this was to just use the shape tool and draw a line across a textbox/table, and then copy that line down for multiple lines.